# how to show legend items of patches in bokeh

Tags: python, legend, bokeh, legend-properties

In the following set up, I create a area chart based on the basic example. How do I get the legend for my input automatically or even programatically. For now I get only legend with one item 'a' and the first color.

```
from bokeh.plotting import *

...
patches([x2 for a in areas], list(areas.values()), color=colors, alpha=0.8,
    line_color=None, legend='a', title="hello chart")

legend().orientation = "top_right" # what other options, may here?
show()
```

What is the format to pass into patches for the legend as value or how can I trigger the legend() to show an item and color for every item in the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following comment in bokeh and stay tuned:

**OK, these hand drawn legends are pretty clunky, will be improved in future release**

This is working for now:

```
hold() # stop the curplot() 
# and add the legend just next to the data
x, y = 15.5, 0
for i,area in enumerate(areas):
    rect([x], [y], color=colors[i], width=0.3, height=400)
    text([x], [y], text=area, angle=0, text_font_size="8pt", text_align="center", text_baseline="middle")
    y = y + 100

show()
```

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm looking for something similar.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer using `patches`, but you can use multiple `patch`:

```
from bokeh.plotting import *

...
for a, area in enumerate(areas):
    p.patch(x2, areas[area], color=colors[a], legend=area, alpha=0.8, line_color=None)

show()
```

which shows the legend for each area nicely.