# Categorical Area with legend outside plot and hovertool in Python Bokeh

Tags: python, charts, categories, bokeh, area

Does anyone know how to add plot outside legend for python bokeh area chart? I tried to plot categorical area chart, which look really cool adapting below examples:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/brewer.html

[Bokeh patches plot with dates as x-axis shifts the ticks one to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426410/bokeh-patches-plot-with-dates-as-x-axis-shifts-the-ticks-one-to-the-right)

[how to show legend items of patches in bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295853/how-to-show-legend-items-of-patches-in-bokeh)

Up to this point, I would like to add legend outside plot, which I saw other answers but still not working in this case. I tried in the loop

```
legend = Legend(items=[LegendItem(label=dict(field="area"), renderers=[r])], location=(0, -30)) 
p.add_layout(legend, 'right')
```

which gave me: RuntimeError: Plot Figure(id= ...) configured with more than one legend renderer

I'd like also to add then HavorTool and ColumnDataSource. Any helps would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I tried to add legend outside plot and HavorTool.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.palettes import brewer
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook, output_file
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.models import LegendItem, Legend

output_notebook()
N = 20
categories = ['y' + str(x) for x in range(10)]
data = {}
data['x'] = np.arange(1,N+1)
for cat in categories:
    data[cat] = np.random.randint(10, 100, size=N)

data11= pd.DataFrame(data)

data11 = data11.set_index(['x'])

def stacked(df, categories):
    areas = dict()
    last = np.zeros(len(df[categories[0]]))
    for cat in categories:
        next = last + df[cat]
        areas[cat] = np.hstack((last[::-1], next))
        last = next
    return areas

areas = stacked(data11, categories)

colors = brewer["Spectral"][len(areas)]

x2 = np.hstack((data['x'][::-1], data['x']))

timesteps = [str(x.date()) for x in pd.date_range('1950-01-01', '1951-08-01', freq='MS')]
p = figure(x_range=timesteps, y_range=(0, 800), toolbar_location="above")

p.grid.minor_grid_line_color = '#eeeeee'
for i, area in enumerate(areas):
    r = p.patch(x2, areas[area], color=colors[i], legend=area, alpha=0.8, line_color=None)
    ''' Add legend below that would match for each area? '''
    #legend = Legend(items=[LegendItem(label=dict(field="area"), renderers=[r])], location=(0, -30)) 
    #p.add_layout(legend, 'right') 

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('category', '@categories'), 
                             ('(y0,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9)','(@areas[y0], @areas[y1], @areas[y3], @areas[y4], @areas[y5], @areas[y6], @areas[y7], @areas[y8],@areas[y9])')]) 
p.add_tools(hover) #Add HavorTool not work? 

p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = np.pi/4

show(p)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kpvX.png)

Comment: Actually, I was be able to get legend outside the plot to work but not yet the hover tool... really wondering if stacked function can be improved to add hover tool. For reference code is below:

Comment: labels = []
for i, area in enumerate(areas):
    r = p.patch(x2, areas[area], color=colors[i], alpha=0.8, line_color=None)
    labels.append(LegendItem(label=dict(value=area), renderers=[r]))
    ''' Save each legend into a list (labels) and add below'''
legend = Legend(items=labels, location=(0, -30)) 
p.add_layout(legend, 'right')